# mongo db find operation query is not working

Tags: mongodb

Am new to mongodb

`db.myjobs.find()` gets following results

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52849a7b8dd61980d1b49b87"), "browser" : "FF20", "id" : "70", "jobs" : [ { "_id" : "5281d1680d0f2f2aaec5787e",   "date" : "Tue Nov 12 2013 12:27:44 GMT+0530 (IST)", "id" : "29" } ],  "os" : "VM-WIN7-64", "server" : "172.16.2.120" }
```

from the above result i have to return  `"os" : "VM-WIN7-64"` on the basis of `id=29` inside `jobs`

am using following code and it is not correct.

```
db.myjobs.find( { id: 29 } )
```

How can i get `"os" : "VM-WIN7-64"` by inputting `id`(id=29) inside `jobs`  no need to get `os` details using `"id":"70"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
db.myjobs.find( { "jobs.id": "29" } )
```

MongoDB doesn't perform recursive searches so if want to find field in nested document you have to provide a path to the field using dot notation.

Moreover fields in MongoDB are typed so string `"29"` is not equal to number `29`

Comment: But it is not easy to beat you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use dot operator to go inside of the object.

```
db.myjobs.find({
   "jobs.id": "29"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

db.myjobs.find({"jobs.id":"29"},{"_id":0,"os":1})